# Desktop twist, does anyone know how to implement this effect in DirectX?

Tags: graphics, directx

http://my.tv.sohu.com/u/vw/26933139

I didn't know what the exactly name for this effect, so I just paste the link of the video here, I want to know what is the knowledge background needed if I want to create such a effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The twisting/distorting effect can be done by making a triangle mesh that is initially a rectangle covering the screen, but with a fair amount of subdivision.  Then you let the user alter the shape by clicking and dragging.  One way to do that is by soft selection: when they click, you find all the verts within a certain distance of the pointer and compute weights that vary smoothly from 1.0 at the pointer to zero at the outside of the radius; then you adjust the positions of the points by weight * the drag vector.  Another way to do it might be with a soft-body physics model, although that's a lot trickier.

You apply an image to it by simply putting a texture on the mesh.  How they get the Windows desktop to be the texture I don't know.  It's pretty easy to get a static screenshot of the desktop as your program starts up, and use that as a texture, but that wouldn't let you interact with it and get an updated render.  In Vista/Win7 with the [DWM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager) it *might* be possible to get it to let you look at the composited desktop render target.  However in the video it looks like Windows XP.  I suspect there might actually be two computers running, one "slave" that displays the desktop normally, and one "master" that captures the slave's video signal and uses that as a texture in the distortion program.  That's just a guess, though.

Comment: I agree with the idea: just get a screenshot and map it to the mesh, but there is a big problem, the mesh itself is on the desktop, so when you get a screenshot, you will capture the mesh also, and when you map the screenshot to the mesh, it's not a pure desktop texture, it's a desktop contains a mesh! so it will be a infinite embedded mesh，

Comment: @zdd That's why I suggested there might be two computers running.